# jquery - postion relative to an element outside the window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

I have a table and a div and I want to positon the div relative to table cells, using position():

```
var td1= $('#td1');
$("#Div1").position( { of: td1, my: 'left top', at: 'left top', offset: '0 5'} );
```

if td1 is inside the window (without horizonal scrolling), the div is placed correctly. However, if the table is wider than the window, the div is placed wrongly (pushed to the left) - position().top is correct, but position().left is such that the div will be entirely inside the window. I tried to put the table inside a div whose width is big enough (wider than the window), but I still see the same behaviour.

Any suggestions as to how to position the div correctly also relative to an element which is outside the window?

Comment: Can you post your HTML or a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It seems jQuery UI only allows "fitting" the positioned element inside the window, using the `collision` property. You can have the same functionality without jQuery UI, just by using `.css` and `.offset`. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/XtV4K/

jQuery UI version that keeps the div in view (though not at the exact spot):

```
$(this).position({
            of: $("#td1"),
            my: "left top",
            at: "left top",
            offset: "0 5",
            collision: "fit"
        })
```

jQuery version that keeps the div exactly where needed:

```
 $(this).css({
            left: $("#td2").offset().left + "px",
            top: $("#td2").offset().top + 5 + "px"
        });
```